# r e n a m e spaces

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-request

We have two tags which seem to be text based: [tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tabs) & [spaces](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spaces).

However, tabs is defined for the graphical user interface feature that allows multiple documents to be contained within a single window, and spaces is tagged as the OS X moniker for "Virtual Desktops".

There were quite a few questions tagged with combinations such as [text](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/text), [spaces](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spaces) and [tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tabs).  I cleaned most of them; all remaining [spaces](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spaces) questions are about OS X.

However, to avoid confusion in the future, I propose to rename "spaces" to something more easily recognized, e.g., spaces-for-OSX. (suggestions welcome).

Is there any system to do this?
Is there any support to do this?
Should I asked the same for tags?

Comment: How about `osx-spaces`?

Comment: Nice, clean and readable.  Spaces-osc was only suggested because it would autocomplete/auto-show for people who started with spaces.

Comment: Maybe we should else create a usage guidance for the tag `tab` in which we can write _"It is not the right tag for the TAB key or the formatting TAB space "_... whatever some of us can think about the following, for me __it is needed to define what we are speaking about__ even when it seems us trivial, because it can not be the same for other people...

Comment: Maybe we can solve this by forcing a tag description when a tag is created?

Comment: I agree else it is unavoidable that we have to spend more time to clean-up, or we are forced to leave _dirty_ the site.

Answer (score 2):

I renamed the tag to [osx-spaces](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx-spaces).